# how to include bootstrap for making my webpage responsive?

Tags: php

I want my webpage to be responsive, I knew it can be done using bootstrap but the thing is where do i include it in my .css file and I want to know whether can I include my own positioning when I use bootstrap or is shouldn't?

Comment: Well now I would say: possible dupe: http://getbootstrap.com/ , but sadly that's not possible

Comment: U say that i cant use my own postioning if I use bootstrap?

Comment: @rizier123 can u tell me cleary because I am very confused in this issue...!! U say that I must include it and remove all the positioning properties ?

Comment: Use bootstrap structure with css.

Comment: Alexander, can I use my positioning after that bootstrap code using my own <style> tags ?

Answer (score 1):

You include it in the `<head>` section. See example.
If you have any custom CSS, include it under `bootstrap.min.css`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom_style.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Place content here -->
</body>
</html>
```